# Mathematica not assuming real parameters

Tags: complex

I have this expression:

```
Eqn = (Cgd rg)/(Cgd+Cgs)+(Cgs rg)/(Cgd+Cgs)-I/(w (Cgd+Cgs))
```

When I try to evaluate it:

```
Refine[Re[Eqn], {Cgd, Cgs, rg, w} \[Element] Reals]
```

I obtain:

Im[1/((Cgd + Cgs) w)] +
Re[(Cgd rg)/(Cgd + Cgs) + (Cgs rg)/(Cgd + Cgs)]

Why??

Why is Mathematica not assuming the symbols to be real...

Comment: There is the capital letter "I" in the expression. Did you intend to put an imaginary unit here?

Comment: It is the imaginary unit, it just got replaced by an I when I copied the expression

Answer (score 3):

Use `ReIm` to separate the real and the imaginary parts.

```
ComplexExpand[ReIm[eqn]]
```

$$\left\{\frac{\text{Cgd} \text{ rg}}{\text{Cgd}+\text{Cgs}}+\frac{\text{Cgs} \text{ rg}}{\text{Cgd}+\text{Cgs}},-\frac{1}{w (\text{Cgd}+\text{Cgs})}\right\}$$

```
First@ComplexExpand[ReIm[eqn]] // Simplify
```

> rg

Answer (score 2):

From the codumentation

```
Re[expr] is left unevaluated if expr is not a numeric quantity.
```

To remove the imaginary part of an expression you need to use `ComplexExpand`

Simple example

```
test = x + I y;
Re[test]
ComplexExpand[Re[test]]
```

> `-Im[y] + Re[x]`

> `x`

Your example

```
Assuming[Cgd ∈ Reals && Cgs ∈ Reals && 
  rg ∈ Reals && w ∈ Reals, 
 ComplexExpand[Re[Eqn]] // Simplify]
```

> `rg`

Edit: sorry, I played a bit with Mathematica. The following is precisely how to go about your problem

```
Refine[ComplexExpand[Re[Eqn]]] // Simplify
```

> `rg`

I just added a `Simplify`

Edit 2: I forgot that you can also use `ReIm` like so:

```
ComplexExpand[ReIm[Eqn]]
```

which yields a list

> `{(Cgd rg)/(Cgd + Cgs) + (Cgs rg)/(Cgd + Cgs), -(1/((Cgd + Cgs) w))}`

and then

```
ComplexExpand[ReIm[Eqn]][[1]] // Simplify
```

> `rg`